# Transpose columns in python/pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to rearrange a dataframe with 5 variables

```
Data columns (total 7 columns):
Nane      3966  non-null values
Value1    3966  non-null values
Value2    3966  non-null values
Value3    3966  non-null values
Value4    3966  non-null values
Value5    3966  non-null values
Period    3966  non-null values
```

I'd like period to be the columns, and the other ones as rows.

So

```
Name Value1 .... Value 5 Period becomes

Period 1 period 2 period3 .... period 3966   
Name  
Value 1  
...  
Value 5
```

I've tried using the stack/unstack and the transpose function, but I just can't figure it out. Does anyone have any pointers ?

Answer (score 6):

You want to use the `Period` as an index. `set_index` will do this for you. Then you can transpose your resulting table:

```
df.set_index('Period').T
Out[13]: 
Period         2010         2011         2012
Name            foo          bar          nil
Value1  0,994369885   0,92930566  0,997754262
Value2  0,780942307  0,274566936  0,488064461
Value3  0,510782105  0,390724018  0,642086396
Value4  0,842522334  0,613705323  0,028703768
Value5  0,383279727  0,287280101  0,764773601
```