# Swap axes of a multidimensional Python list

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, multidimensional-array, python-2.x

How to swap the axes of a multidimensional Python list?

For example, if the multidimensional Python list is `input = [[1,2], [3,4,5],[6]]`, I would like to have `output = [[1,3,6], [2,4], [5]]` as output.

[`numpy.swapaxes`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) allows to do so for an array, but it doesn't support the case where a dimension has a varying size, as in the given example. Same issue with the typical `map(list, zip(*l))`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose columns in python/pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380670/transpose-columns-in-python-pandas)

Comment: @msw The linked question assumes each dimension has a fixed size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
print [[i for i in element if i is not None] for element in  list(izip_longest(*input))]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3, 6], [2, 4], [5]]
```

([`iterools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) was introduced in Python 2.6.)

Comment: Note that `izip_longest` was changed to `zip_longest` in Python3 (as it now returns an iterator rather than a list).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

input  = [[1,2], [3,4,5],[6]]

df = pd.DataFrame(input).T

output = [[element for element in row if not np.isnan(element)] for row in df.values]
```

Output

```
 [[1.0, 3.0, 6.0], [2.0, 4.0], [5.0]]
```